# Change property for every value in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click

You can see in my fiddle that the value for each name is set to 0.

I'd like my changeAllValues() to change all the

```
value: 0's
```

to be

```
value: 1's!
```

What is the best way to do this?

**JS Fiddle:**
https://jsfiddle.net/purple_lightsaber/edegcLnh/

PS:

```
ng-click="changeAllValues()
```

must be outside of my ng-repeat like it is in the fiddle.

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this,

```
 $scope.changeAllValues = function() {
      angular.forEach($scope.names, function(item) {
        item["value"] = 1;
      })
    }
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/3y4djqjk/)**